# Leading zero-fill of integer variable

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I'm trying to create a new variable where numbers between 0 and 9 should always be represented as 00...09 instead of 0...9. Here is my test without the actual command for POC purposes:

```
for i in {00..23}; do hourPlus=$((i+1)); echo $i $hourPlus; done
```

Which outputs:

```
00   1
01   2
02   3
03   4
04   5
05   6
06   7
07   8
08   9
09   10
10   11
11   12
12   13
13   14
14   15
15   16
16   17
17   18
18   19
19   20
20   21
21   22
22   23
23   24
```

However, I was expecting something like:

```
00   01
01   02
02   03
03   04
04   05
05   06
06   07
07   08
08   09
09   10
10   11
11   12
12   13
13   14
14   15
15   16
16   17
17   18
18   19
19   20
20   21
21   22
22   23
23   24
```

Anyone knows how to get this to work properly for my for loop for work as I'm expecting?

Comment: Apologies for not being as descriptive as I should have been. I added echo as a way to demonstrate the issue, however my script will perform another task using variable $i and $hourPlus. The printf solution wouldn't work in this case, as I need to use the value stored in that to do something else

Comment: Did you have a look at my functions? They are re-usable, whatever you are doing.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a function that would work for you:

```sh
two_digits_zero_fill ()
{
    # print the number as a string with a leading zero
    printf '%02d\n' "$1"
}
```

---

or even more universal:

```sh
leading_zero_fill ()
{
    # print the number as a string with a given number of leading zeros
    printf "%0$1d\\n" "$2"
}
```

usage of the latter:

```sh
number=7
leading_zero_fill 3 "$number"
```

will print out:

> ```
> 007
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Replace echo part with

```
printf '%02d %02d\n' $i $hourPlus
```

Edit: in fact, unless you are using the final value of hourPlus:

```
for i in {0..23}; do printf '%02d %02d\n' $i $((i + 1)); done
```

Answer (score 1):

With `ksh` (which doesn't support `{00..23}` though you can use `{0..23%02d}` in ksh93) or `zsh` (where that `{00..23}` expansion comes from), that's with:

```
typeset -Z2 var
```

Then:

```
$ var=0
$ echo "$var"
00
$ ((var++))
$ echo "$var"
01
```

Note that it only affects the expansion of the variable, not of arithmetic expansions:

```
$ echo "$((var+1))"
2
```

Note that the variable is also *truncated* to two digits:

```
$ var=123
$ echo "$var"
23
zsh$ echo $((var)) # value is still 123, only the expansion is truncated
123
ksh$ echo "$((var))" # value truncated upon assignment
23
```

In `zsh`, see also `${(l:2::0:)expansion}` to left-pad (and truncate) an expansion with zeros  to length 2.

POSIXly, you can always use:

```
printf '%02d\n' "$var"
```

but note that it does not *truncate* to 2 digits (which is just as well in most cases) and only works with decimal integer strings:

Beware of:

```
$ bash -c "printf '%02d\n' 010"
08
```

(same with yash, dash or GNU `printf`, that's actually a POSIX requirement).

Answer (score 0):

If you expect to get some type of format, you should ask for it specifically.

Printing an integer number (`$int`) with a fixed width of n digits with leading zeros if the width is not filled could be done with:

```
printf '%0*d' "$n" "$int"
```

Example:

```
$ printf '%0*d' 4 25
0025

$ printf '%0*d' 10 7
0000000007
```

To print any number with **one** leading zero:

```
$ printf '0%d' 7
07
```

## octal

But in the shell (except ksh and zsh) a number `08` generates an error:

```
$ dash -c 'i=08; echo $((i+1))'
dash: 1: Illegal number: 08
```

That's because, in some shells, a number that starts with a zero is interpreted as a number in base 8 (octal). In octal the number 8 doesn't exists. So, you need some other way to do the math, like bc:

```
$ i="008"; echo "$i + 1 " | bc
9
```

In short, you need something like:

```
for i in {00..23}; do hP=$( echo "$i+1" |bc ); printf '%s %02d\n' "$i" "$hP"; done
```